# ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test'

Tags: mysql, linux, database, centos, innodb

I am trying to install mySQL server on CentOS6.6 **without root access**. 
Here are my steps.

1. Unpack **mysql-8.0.11**-linux-glibc2.12-i686 in a directory(EX:[Base MySQL Directory])
2. Initialize and generate root password: 
   `./mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --lc_messages_dir=[Base MySQL Directory]/share --basedir=[Base MySQL Directory] --datadir=[BaseMySQL Directory]/data --log-error=[Base MySQL Directory]/data/mysql.err --pid-file=[Base MySQL Directory]/mysql.pid --socket=[Base MySQL Directory]/thesock --port=3306 &`
3. Start the server: 
   `./mysqld --user=mysql --basedir=[Base MySQL Directory] --lc_messages_dir=[Base MySQL Directory]/share --datadir=[Base MySQL Directory]/data --log-error=[Base MySQL Directory]/data/mysql.err --pid-file=[Base MySQL Directory]/mysql.pid --socket=[Base MySQL Directory]/thesock --port=3306 &`
4. Access MySQL database: 
   `./mysql --socket=$MYSQL_TED_HOME/thesock --user=root --password="IL-Rp=Wj*3dg"`

But I got an Error message:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test'
```

I know there are already tons of questions like "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database....
". But I couldn't find any of them is similar to mine.

Here is "mysql.err":

```
[Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
[Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
[Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

[Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
[Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
[Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: ec2d7935-43d0-11e8-96ee-d89d6726c984.
[Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
[Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: IL-Rp=Wj*3dg
[Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
[Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
[Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
[Note] ./mysqld (mysqld 5.7.13) starting as process 6390 ...
[Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

[Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support not available
[Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
[Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
[Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
[Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
[Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
[Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
[Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
[Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
[Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
[Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
[Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
[Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
[Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
[Note] InnoDB: 5.7.13 started; log sequence number 2524437
[Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from [Base MySQL Directory]/mysql-5.7.13-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64/data/ib_buffer_pool
[Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
[Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
[Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
[Note] IPv6 is available.
[Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
[Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180419 20:55:57
[Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
[Note] ./mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.13'  socket: '[Base MySQL Directory]/thesock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can get root access?  I have installed/configured MySQL many times, and I have no recollection of it being this ugly.

Comment: Well, that is the point. I need to install it w/o root access.....

Comment: At least you know that MySQL is in fact running.  I don't see `test` being specified as the database anywhere.  Any chance you can request a database which is known to exist?

Comment: I guess there is only way to check the existing database list - login and command. But now I still face this issue while login.....

Comment: Quick question. Do you think install it in virtual environment or any virtual machines is good idea or not. This nightmare is all because I couldn't get root access from IT.....

Comment: For development purposes, that might be fine.  At least you can avoid this problem for now, and come back later when you have more time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hope it works. :)

Comment: Even though change to latest version mysql-8.0.11-1, the issue is same....